# Subtracting Time.now from End_time (UTC) gives me a float (hhmmss.xx). How do I format it to HH:MM so that I can use it for a countdown timer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `end_time` that I would like to create a timer for `end_time.utc - Time.now`. However, when I subtract the value, I get a float like `23510.29642` which I found to represent hours, minutes,seconds followed by a period and milliseconds.

```
end_time
=>  Wed, 04 Jun 2014 19:00:00 UTC +00:00 

end_time.utc - Time.now
=> -24614.329399
```

How do I format the float so that I get `-2:46` without manually parsing the string?

Comment: You may want to use `Time.current` (shortcut for `Time.zone.now`) which is timezone aware - also http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words AND http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words might be helpful in some cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between two Time objects returns number of seconds between two times.

```
e = Time.parse("Wed, 04 Jun 2014 19:00:00 UTC +00:00")
diff = e - Time.parse("Wed, 04 Jun 2014 21:49:00 UTC +00:00")

hours = (diff / 3600).to_i
minutes = (diff / 60).to_i % 60 # if e < Time.now then minutes = (diff / 60).to_i % 60 - 60
seconds = diff.to_i % 60 # same as minutes

puts hours # -2
puts minutes # -49
puts seconds # 0
```